# How do I replace the placeholder in the footer?

Tags: phpword, phpoffice

there is a code like this:

```php
$templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor('path to DOCX file.....');

$table = new Table(['unit' => TblWidth::AUTO]);

$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(null, [
    'borderTopColor' => 'ff0000',
    'borderTopSize' => 1,
    'borderRightColor' => 'ff0000',
    'borderRightSize' => 1,
    'borderLeftColor' => 'ff0000',
    'borderLeftSize' => 1,
])->addText('bla bla bla', ['Color' => 'ff0000']);

$templateProcessor->setComplexValue('{bla_bla_bla_placeholder}', $table);
```

The problem is that if the `{bla_bla_bla_placeholder}` is in the footer, it is not replaced, via: `$templateProcessor->setComplexValue('{bla_bla_bla_placeholder}', $table);`

And if it is in the body of the page, it is replaced as I expect it to be.

Can you please tell me how to replace the placeholder in the footer? `.docx` file format

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question. For some reason my placeholder replacement didn't work through `$templateProcessor->setComplexValue` in the footer. So I made a table in .docx file in the cell of which I inserted placeholder and then through the usual replacement placeholder `$templateProcessor->setValue` works even in the header